# java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncWaitStrategyFactoryConfig"'s signer information does not match signer

Tags: log4j2, tomcat9, jasperserver

Getting Error when starting tomcat 9
isuue with log4j-1.2-api-2.20.0.jar but when use log4j-core-2.17.1.jar, everthing is loading fine

```
12-Mar-2024 15:46:40.622 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\jasperserver-pro]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:720)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1133)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1867)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:1045)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:429)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1576)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:936)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:343)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:474)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/jasperserver-pro]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        ... 37 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.crypto.EncryptionEngine.<clinit>(EncryptionEngine.java:62)
        at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.tomcat.jndi.JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(JSCommonsBasicDataSourceFactory.java:78)
        at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
        at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:332)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:857)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:160)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
        at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:174)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1017)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:557)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:253)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5056)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 38 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot parse pattern '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n'
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$SerializerBuilder.build(PatternLayout.java:490)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:140)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.<init>(PatternLayout.java:61)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$Builder.build(PatternLayout.java:770)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.setToDefault(AbstractConfiguration.java:723)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.DefaultConfiguration.<init>(DefaultConfiguration.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<init>(LoggerContext.java:95)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:140)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:309)
        at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy$PrivateLogManager.getContext(Hierarchy.java:86)
        at org.apache.log4j.Hierarchy.getContext(Hierarchy.java:99)
        at org.apache.log4j.Category.<init>(Category.java:188)
        at org.apache.log4j.Logger.<init>(Logger.java:57)
        at org.apache.log4j.spi.RootLogger.<init>(RootLogger.java:39)
        at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:72)
        ... 52 more
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: class "org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncWaitStrategyFactoryConfig"'s signer information does not match signer information of other classes in the same package
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.checkCerts(ClassLoader.java:891)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.preDefineClass(ClassLoader.java:661)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:754)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2419)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.decodeCacheFiles(PluginRegistry.java:181)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginRegistry.loadFromMainClassLoader(PluginRegistry.java:119)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginManager.collectPlugins(PluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:132)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.PatternParser.<init>(PatternParser.java:113)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout.createPatternParser(PatternLayout.java:255)
        at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.layout.PatternLayout$SerializerBuilder.build(PatternLayout.java:473)
```

We are trying to upgrade jasperserver. Using Amazon correto 1.8 and tomcat 9